# iterating over numpy matrix columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following numpy matrix:

```
        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      
0       0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
1       0.0    0.0    5.0    0.0    9.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
2       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
3       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    5.0    0.0   
4       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
5       0.0    0.0    7.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
6       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
7       5.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    6.0    0.0    0.0   
8       2.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    3.0    0.0    6.0    0.0    8.0    0.0   
9       0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
10      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

I want to calculate the non-zero values average of every row and column separately. So my result should be something like this:

```
average_rows = [1.0,7.0,2.0,5.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,5.5,4.75,1.0,0.0]
average_cols = [3.5,1.0,4.33333,0.0,4.33333,0.0,4.0,6.0,6.5,0.0]
```

I can't figure out how to iterate over them, and I keep getting `TypeError: unhashable type`

Also, I'm not sure if iterating is the best solution, I also tried something like `R[:,i]` to grab each column and sum it using `sum(R[:,i])`, but keep getting the same error.

Comment: How did you get this neat tabular display? It isn't normal `numpy`. With row and column labels it looks like `pandas`,. What **exactly** do you mean by `matrix`?

Comment: It's numpy. I start off with `R = np.zeros((Rrows, Rcols))`, then iterated and filled up the non-zero values, it's mostly a sparse matrix. It could be nicely displayed since I use ipython notebook.

Comment: Ok, I use Ipython all the but not the notebook.  But if that's the ``R` I don't see where `unhashable` error comes from.  When reporting errors you should show at least part of the error stack and the code line that produced it.

Comment: You could try [transposing the matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html) and iterating with `sum` over the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use 2d `np.array` instead of matrix.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 4]], dtype='float')
data[data == 0] = np.nan
# replace all zeroes with `nan`'s to skip them
# [[  1.   2.  nan]
# [ nan  nan   1.]
# [ nan   2.   4.]]
np.nanmean(data, axis=0)
# array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])
np.nanmean(data, axis=1)
# array([ 1.5,  1. ,  3. ])
```

Comment: It's a large matrix that I have (9,000 x 15,000). And I'm not sure how to change it to an np.array.

Comment: Just feed it to `np.array`: `np.array(np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))`. `np.array` is perfectly okay to work with large 2d arrays.

Comment: The only reason why `np.matrix` exists is its behaviour with `*` operator: it do matrix multiplication instead of elementwise for `np.matrix`. But now we have `@` to do matrix multiplication, so we don't need `np.matrix` at all.

Comment: Thanks! it mostly works, but tends to put nan in columns / rows where is it all zeros instead of zero

Comment: You can use `np.nan_to_num()` to eliminate these nans. (However, strictly speaking, this is a correct behaviour: the average of empty set of number is a kind of nan, not zero :) )

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it is `np.matrix` or `np.array`. Iteration over columns or summation my row works the same.

Comment: @hpaulj, good point, thanks. I haven't actually worked much with `np.matrix` as it is more or less deprecated.

Comment: It's primarily an array that must be 2d.